# Is there a fast way/trick to add one bit at the beginning of a file?

Tags: c++, optimization, bit, bitwise-operators

For a special algorithm I have to **add (or remove) several times one bit** at the beginning of a file. It must be a bit and not a whole byte like '0000 0001'.

After that I don't have to overwrite the file with the new content, so it is sufficient if I edit the file data just in memory. For this algorithm I can add one byte like '0000 0000' or '1000 0000' to the end of the file data.

You can summarize it as a bitshift over a whole file. I already tried it on my own. I read the file in integers (32 bit), bitshifted them in each case to the right and transfered the last bit from the integer before to the first position.

But this method is definitely not fast enough. I also searched the internet but I couldn't find anything like this. Is there perhaps a possibility to do this faster?

Comment: There's no way to do that efficiently. Why would you need it?

Comment: unless I am missing something, It means you would require a shift on every byte in the file, which is definitely not efficient.

Comment: I checked out the implementation of `boost::dynamic_bitset::operator>>=` and it is also implemented using a `for` loop and element-wise bit-shifts.  Since the smallest addressable unit in C++ is a byte, I don't think this can be avoided.  You might, however, gain a speedup by using a larger integer type, such as `uintmax_t`.  In any case, use an unsigned type to stay in well-defined behavior.

Comment: If the resulting file is for your own use, you could consider writing another file describing which bits to add or remove. Then you have to do the bit-shifting when you use the file. A bit like a [EDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_decision_list) used in video editing.

Comment: You can't do that effeciently even in RAM. You'll need either shift entire array (if 1 bit <=> 1 bit of RAM) or keep at least 1 byte of RAM per 1 bit (makes memory consumption 8 times larger).

Comment: Unless the compiler is clever enough to work out what you're doing, the generated code will include a number of accesses on each and every element in the array, whether they be bytes or longs. Something that may be worth considering is use of some inline assembly and most particularly - use of the RCR instruction in conjunction with SAHF and LAHF would temporarily store the bit shifted out of one element and then shift it into the next element - all without needing to mask bits. I'm not sure if the required instructions would stall the pipeline or not, if not - it'd be quick. Give it a whirl!

Comment: @myaut - are you familiar with the x86's RCR, LAHF and SAHF instructions?

Comment: @enhzflep: even in that case you'll need rewrite entire memory chunk you shifting. It's O(n) algorithm regardless of constant you'll get (which depends on caching effeciency and generated asm code)

Comment: Let's say you have a file with (say) 10 bytes, each represented using 8 bits (total of 80 bits).   You do a bit shift.   The minimum size of the file will now be 11 bytes, since the smallest unit by which a file is read or written is a byte.   How will you distinguish between a file with 81 bits and one with 90 bits?

Comment: @myaut - indeed, I certainly don't claim otherwise, hence my mention of pipeline stalls - efficiently performing the task would necessarily depend on the hardware that the code was run on. I'd expect to outdo many if not most compilers in this particular task. (I may well be under/over estimating compiler writers and myself) I'm not even sure LLVM would be clever enough to perform the operation I suggest with the use of the carry flag.

Comment: Do you really need to shift the entire file? Or are you merely reading the file bit by bit? You could just have a variable that remembers how many bits were shifted, and adjust all read requests by that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is: there is no way to do this efficiently.

The long answer is actually a series of new questions: what do you really intend to achieve with this? What do you even mean exactly by *shifting one bit at the beginning of a file*?

You mention reading the file in 32 bit chunks (`int`, or better `uint32_t`) and shifting them one at a time: there is a byte ordering issue in doing it this way.  It is not portable as some CPUs will read `uint32_t` in little endian order (Intel architecture) and some others in big endian order (Motorola, PowerPC, ea).

Even the order of bits in bytes is somewhat confusing: By *shifting a bit at the beginning of the file*, do you mean setting bit 0x80 of the first byte or bit 0x01 of the first byte?  Bitmap files and graphics cards have conflicting conventions to this regard.

If this bit file is specified outside of your program, you should be very careful about these details.  If it is your own invention, a change of algorithm might be helpful to simplify this situation.

Comment: Thanks for all your helpful responses. I already thought that it isn't possible but i hoped that there is a trick or sth like that. Your explanations are very logical and I've now noticed that there is no fast/efficient way. And yes it is a homemade algorithm, therefore I have realized that I must improve this algorithm.